# ¿Porque no puedo acceder a la base de datos SQL server mediante eloquent pero si puedo hacer migraciones con seeders laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server, eloquent

hola estoy haciendo una pagina web con laravel 10 el problema es que en mi controlador quiero acceder a los usuarios pero este me manda un error:

```
SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. (Connection: sqlsrv, SQL: select * from [users])
```

este es mi codigo en el controlador:

```
 public function Show()
 {
    //Aqui da el error
    $user = User::all();
    return view('login', compact('user'));
 }
```

pero si yo lo uso en un seeder este si funciona o incluso si uso tinker

```
> User::all()
[!] Aliasing 'User' to 'App\Models\User' for this Tinker session.
= Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4281
all: [
  App\Models\User {#4896
    id: "1",
    name: "Admin",
    email: "admin@outlook.com",
    email_verified_at: null,
    #password: "$2y$10$LnmDiik30E4hG0l60TDAc.6DFOpT1biVFgw0S17FYA76z984vL0YO",
    #remember_token: null,
    created_at: "2023-04-04 23:09:18.317",
    updated_at: "2023-04-04 23:09:18.317",
  },
  App\Models\User {#4897
    id: "2",
    name: "Client",
    email: "client@outlook.com",
    email_verified_at: null,
    #password: "$2y$10$Lgj7edeSsS.XBYixU181CuPOyoxUsFzLu1gzSeHWwb8VrZmcZiOCG",
    #remember_token: null,
    created_at: "2023-04-04 23:09:18.423",
    updated_at: "2023-04-04 23:09:18.423",
  },
],
}
```

este es el codigo del seeder:

```
public function run(): void
{
    User::Create([
        'name' => 'Admin',
        'email' => 'admin@outlook.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('1234'),
    ])->assignRole('Admin');

    User::Create([
        'name' => 'Client',
        'email' => 'client@outlook.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('1234'),
    ])->assignRole('Client');
}
```

estas dos ultimas opciones funcionan correctamente menos en el controlador, ya instale las extensiones de php pero aun asi no funciona
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tambien añadi los .dll en la carpeta del php 8.2.0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien me podria ayudar??

Comment: Pon tu archivo `.env` y verifica si todo es correcto en el.

Comment: Verifica que no tengas una contraseña que te pueda erorr en diferentes ocasiones, una vez utilicé una contraseña generada automaticamente y tenia caracteres que me daba error en algunas situaciones y en otras no.